# using htaccess rewrite rule for URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this in my ht access file:

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteRule ^page1$ home.php?id=page1 [N]
```

so when i go to domain.com/page it shows `domain.com/home.php?id=page1`

how can i make it so when more pages are added i dont have to keep adding each page to the ht access file?

so if a page called `page2` is added to the website, you can go to `domain.com/page2` and it will show `domain.com/home.php?id=page2`

but no changes are made to the HT Access file?

Comment: this is the most longwinded example of url rewriting I think I've ever seen.

Comment: There're hundreds of duplicates on SO and thousands on the internet. _Hint:_ search for _mod_rewrite_

Comment: Please please, for the love of the twelve lords of cobol, validate `$_GET['id']` properly, or else people can include files from anywhere on the server. I'm begging you, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1
```

now you can use simple links with .html at the end

they will be translated as follows :

```
exampledomain.com/home.html => exampledomain.com/index.php?page=home
```

**EDIT**

if u dont want .html change second line to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: how can i do it so it doesnt have the .html at the end?

Comment: ok cool thanks. works great. my page content is stored in a database, so if im on domain.com/about-us, this is going to domain.com/index.php?id=about-us but on the index.php page i have a select query that selects where id = '".$_GET["id"]."' but its not working now ive changed this

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)?$ index.php?id=page$1 [QSA]
```